# In Azure logic App can I have more than one starting point(HTTP trigger)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Azure logic apps, can I have more than one starting point, as in HTTP trigger, as I have to create a separate logic app for each integration.

In the Azure logic apps documentation, they have mentioned that through code view it is possible. So my question is, is it possible to have more than one HTTP trigger per workflow?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/fnord

Comment: you should have a look at eventgrid, it could do the trick in your case

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried with multiple http triggers but we had situations wherein we had to handle different http requests and we handled that by creating a section for message payload in the JSON message, creating different message type identifier for each payload type and then handling them as separate case statement in the logic app based on message type. Just to give an idea. Not sure if it fits your situation.